# The volume of one of the regions bounded by $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ around the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

Consider one of the regions bounded only by functions $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=\cos(x)$ (say from $x=\frac\pi4$ to $x=\frac{5\pi}4$) Now if that region were to revolve around the $x$ axis, what would be the volume of the resulting shape.

Now, if you consider the region first, it intersects the $x$-axis. Which means that when it gets revolved, some parts are going to be encapsulated twice. To avoid that I tried to divide the region into four sub-regions. Since the shape is symmetric, it seems sufficient to calculate the volume of the first two regions then multiply the answer by $2$.

[image: sub-regions]

The first region is simple, it can be done by the washer method. The top part is $f(x)$ which is $\sin(x)$ and the bottom part is $g(x)$ which is $\cos(x)$. This gives us the volume by the following integral:

$$\pi\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)\ {dx}
=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Now the second region, since in the second region $\sin x$ is strictly bigger than $\cos(x)$. It seems to me that the revolution of $\cos x$ is going to be entirely encapsulated in the revolution of $\sin x$, so it can be ignored. This means that the significant region can be calculated by the disk method. This gives us the volume by the following integral:

$$\pi\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/4}{\sin^2(x)}\ {dx}
=\frac{\pi^2}{8}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

The total volume should be equal to double the sum of the previous two volumes, which should equal to:
$$2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{8}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}(6+\pi)$$

Is that the correct approach to that problem? The answer I got doesn't seem to agree with the answer I got from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=228bc7c11f6524e0a38ceab65fed8f0c).

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me. I'd check to see how that program computes volume.

Comment: How can I figure how it computes volume?

Comment: Look on the website to see if there's an explanation on how they do it. If not, ask the creator yourself.

Comment: Or maybe try to use another program and compare answers. Lots of ways to do things.

Comment: Seems like online programs use: $\pi\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}{\left|\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)\right|\ {dx}}$
Which _should_ fall apart if you set the functions to say $\sin(x)$ and $-\sin(x)$. But it doesn't.

Comment: So you want to rotate by $2\pi$ a shape around an axis which intercepts it ? what is then the definition that you give to the "solid" that is generated ?? If the shape was a blade and you turn it inside a soft "cake", the volume of the void generated will be that of the largest radius of the two halves.

Comment: I have verified your result numerically by an altogether different method

Comment: @CyeWaldman Can you show your different method?

Comment: Sure, perhaps I overstated it a bit. I simply expressed the area to be rotated as a closed curve in the complex plane and then applied Pappus's $2^{nd}$ Centroid Theorem.

Comment: Might be quite interesting to show your work.

Comment: Why does it matter whether a section revolves around the axis multiple times? The volume that the solid encompasses will still be the same.